# Linking invoices from PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible to actually link clients to individual invoices, on PayPal? I'm hoping to use it for an invoice backend system on my website.

I've looked everywhere and literally can't find a solution. I have seen it working inside of WHMCS before.

Answer (score 0):

You mean an invoice created on PayPal's site? Sure its possible. Just send a link like this (with the actual invoice number in place, obviously):

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_pay-inv&id=INV-NUM-123-456-789-012